# Can you get regular achievements in Wesker mode?

Tags: achievements, resident-evil-0

I finished the game once and unlocked "Wesker mode". There are some achievements, that are associated with this mode (like [Welcome to team Wesker](https://www.trueachievements.com/a211386/welcome-to-team-wesker-achievement)), so I'm about to start it, but I'm not sure if I can get regular achievements (like "no mixing herbs" and "no healing spray use") there as well.

Can I get all the regular achievements in Wesker mode? If not, which ones are completable there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, you can.**

I've just finished the Wesker Mode, and I was able to complete following achievements (with couple of reloads of cause):

- no heal run;
- no healing spray use;
- no herb mix;
- all herb mixes;
- kill bosses with Rebecca.

However, there was no rank for me at the results screen, so I assume you cannot get "S rank" achievement in this mode.